# RS.EXE not found

Tags: rs.exe

I have made an application and installing it using installation wizard  in which the application is being installed and in the same process the SSRS installation is called.In which [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzPio.jpg)

a) Report services not being installed when being called within the installation processes.
b) Report services is being installed once being run from the DVD. 
c) RS. exe not found when run through program.
d) RS. exe found when run through DVD.
Snapshot attached

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the rs.exe application off the removable media & use it without an SSRS installation or the removable media. Also, are you sure the application is trying to run the rs.exe app from the D drive and not it's local folder?

In my opinion you'd be better packaging this (rs.exe) up with the application, or a few steps further, you can build the reporting services functionality into a C# application without the rs.exe.

Hope that helps